# Issue with Devart that connects oracle where max pool size is 300

Tags: .net, oracle, devart

We are facing the below-mentioned error in one of our applications quite frequently.
This is impacting the performance of the application. Can you please guide us in solving this issue?

> ERROR: System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This
>   may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max
>   pool size was reached.   at Devart.Common. DbConnectionFactory.b
>   (DbConnectionBase A_0)

The connection string is like this:

```
Max Pool Size=300;Min Pool Size=50;Pooling=True;Connection Timeout=30;Connection LifeTime=0 ;persist security info=True
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you close unused connections in your code to return them to the pool: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/FAQ.html#q56.
2. You can control the max number of connections in the pool with the Max Pool Size connection string parameter.
3. If you do not need pooling, turn off it using "Pooling=false;" in the connection string.

Refer to https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~ConnectionString.html .